# Meeting request not sending emails

Tags: email, leads

I have a problem with sending emails using meeting request, nor i(user) or lead get the email even though the meeting is created on open activities list.

I'm doing this as administrator so i have access to all fields and objects.

This is all done on Sandbox version of our org, could this be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was your sandbox refreshed ? By default when sandbox is refreshed the email access in the settings is set to No Email .

You can set this up in Email Deliverability to "All Emails"

Set up | Email Deliverability and check whether the sandbox has access to send emails .

Comment: No this is the first iteration(no refreshes) of this sandbox.

Comment: Worth checking the Deliverability settings

Comment: Yup just checked it, had to set it to "All email" Thanks for help.